# Mounting an attached EBS volume to a EBS based instance on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have an old Fedora 8 server running on instance store. I just built a Fedora 12 server that is on EBS.  Now I know this may be redundant since my new Fedora 12 instance is on EBS, I would like for my web application to run on an EBS volume that I wish to mount to my new Fedora 12 instance.

I created a new 10 GB volume through Elasticfox.  Then attached it to my Fedora 12 instance and set the device to be /dev/sdh.

Now when I SSH into my Fedora 12 instance, I run the following to partition this new volume:

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdh
```

And I get this error:

> Cannot stat /dev/sda2: No such file or
>   directory

Now if I do the exact same steps above on my old Fedora 8 instance on instance store, it all works fine.

My question is what am I doing wrong?  Can I even attach a EBS volume to an instance that is already running on EBS?

I really appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you partitioned it by fdisk?
user 'fdisk -l' to check all drives in the system. find your new drive then 'fdisk /dev/sdX' where 'X' is letter for your new drive.
check this for info about partitioning:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html

Comment: I did not use fdisk.  Not sure why I need to use that when mkfs worked in the past.  But will certainly try at this point.  THX!